# Matcher is returning some duplicates entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy, matcher

I want output as `["good customer service","great ambience"]` but I am getting `["good customer","good customer service","great ambience"]` because pattern is matching with good customer also but this phrase doesn't make any sense. How can I remove these kind of duplicates

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("good customer service and great ambience")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

# Create a pattern matching two tokens: adjective followed by one or more noun
 pattern = [{"POS": 'ADJ'},{"POS": 'NOUN', "OP": '+'}]

matcher.add("ADJ_NOUN_PATTERN", None,pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
print("Matches:", [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in matches])
```

Comment: You mean to say you want `+` to behave "greedily", only return the longest match from the leftmost index?

Comment: correct @WiktorStribiżew, i want the longest match. can you please help me how I can do it

Comment: can someone please help me out, its really urgent.

Comment: See my answer below, did it work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Yes it worked for me Thanks alot for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may post-process the matches by grouping the tuples against the start index and only keeping the one with the largest end index:

```
from itertools import *

#...

matches = matcher(doc)
results = [max(list(group),key=lambda x: x[2]) for key, group in groupby(matches, lambda prop: prop[1])]    
print("Matches:", [doc[start:end].text for match_id, start, end in results])
# => Matches: ['good customer service', 'great ambience']
```

The `groupby(matches, lambda prop: prop[1])` will group the matches by the start index, here, resulting in `[(5488211386492616699, 0, 2), (5488211386492616699, 0, 3)]` and `(5488211386492616699, 4, 6)`. `max(list(group),key=lambda x: x[2])` will grab the item where end index (Value #3) is the biggest.

Answer (score 1):

Spacy has a built-in function to do just that. Check [filter_spans](https://spacy.io/api/top-level#util.filter_spans):

The documentation says:

> When spans overlap, the (first) longest span is preferred over shorter spans.

Example:

```
doc = nlp("This is a sentence.")
spans = [doc[0:2], doc[0:2], doc[0:4]]
filtered = filter_spans(spans)
```

Comment: If you're trying to filter the results of spacy.matcher.Matcher(), make sure to use `matcher(doc, as_spans=True)`, rather than just `matcher(doc)`