# spacy rule matcher on unit of measure before or after digit

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to spacy and i am trying to match some measurements in some text. My problem is that the unit of measure sometimes is before, sometimes is after the value. In some other cases has a different name. Here is some code:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

# case 1:
text = "the surface is 31 sq"
# case 2:
# text = "the surface is sq 31"
# case 3:
# text = "the surface is square meters 31"
# case 4:
# text = "the surface is 31 square meters"
# case 5:
# text = "the surface is about 31 square meters"
# case 6:
# text = "the surface is 31 kilograms"

pattern = [
    {"IS_STOP": True}, 
    {"LOWER": "surface"}, 
    {"LEMMA": "be", "OP": "?"}, 
    {"LOWER": "sq", "OP": "?"},
    {"LOWER": "square", "OP": "?"},
    {"LOWER": "meters", "OP": "?"},
    {"IS_DIGIT": True}, 
    {"LOWER": "square", "OP": "?"},
    {"LOWER": "meters", "OP": "?"},
    {"LOWER": "sq", "OP": "?"} 
]

doc = nlp(text)

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 

matcher.add("Surface", None, pattern)

matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

I have two problems :
1 - the pattern should be able to match all cases 1 to 5, but in my case 1 the output is

```
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 4 the surface is 31
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 5 the surface is 31 sq
```

which to me seems that it is a duplicate match.

2 - case 6 should not match, but instead, with my pattern it is matched.
Any suggestion on how to improve this?

EDIT:
is it possible to build an OR condition within the pattern? something like

```
pattern = [
    {"POS": "DET", "OP": "?"}, 
    {"LOWER": "surface"}, 
    {"LEMMA": "be", "OP": "?"},  
    [
      [{"LOWER": "sq", "OP": "?"},
      {"LOWER": "square", "OP": "?"},
      {"LOWER": "meters", "OP": "?"},
      {"IS_ALPHA": True, "OP": "?"},
      {"LIKE_NUM": True}]
     OR
      [{"LIKE_NUM": True},
      {"LOWER": "square", "OP": "?"},
      {"LOWER": "meters", "OP": "?"},
      {"LOWER": "sq", "OP": "?"} ]
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an OR like that, but you may define separate patterns for the same label. So, you need two patterns, one will match a number with either `sq` or `square` or `meters` or a combination of these words before it, and another pattern that matches a number with at least one of these words after.

Code snippet:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

texts = ["the surface is 31 sq", "the surface is sq 31", "the surface is square meters 31",
     "the surface is 31 square meters", "the surface is about 31 square meters", "the surface is 31 kilograms"]
pattern1 = [
      {"IS_STOP": True}, 
      {"LOWER": "surface"}, 
      {"LEMMA": "be", "OP": "?"}, 
      {"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "^(?i:sq(?:uare)?|m(?:et(?:er|re)s?)?)$"}, "OP": "+"},
      {"LIKE_NUM": True}
    ]
pattern2 = [
      {"IS_STOP": True}, 
      {"LOWER": "surface"}, 
      {"LEMMA": "be", "OP": "?"}, 
      {"IS_ALPHA": True, "OP": "?"},
      {"LIKE_NUM": True},
      {"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "^(?i:sq(?:uare)?|m(?:et(?:er|re)s?)?)$"}, "OP": "+"}
    ]

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab, validate=True)
matcher.add("Surface", None, pattern1)
matcher.add("Surface", None, pattern2)

for text in texts:
  doc = nlp(text)
  matches = matcher(doc)
  for match_id, start, end in matches:
    string_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]  # Get string representation
    span = doc[start:end]  # The matched span
    print(match_id, string_id, start, end, span.text)
```

Output:

```
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 5 the surface is 31 sq
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 5 the surface is sq 31
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 6 the surface is square meters 31
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 5 the surface is 31 square
4898162435462687487 Surface 0 6 the surface is about 31 square
```

The `{"TEXT" : {"REGEX": "^(?i:sq(?:uare)?|m(?:et(?:er|re)s?)?)$"}, "OP": "+"}` part matches one or more tokens (due to `"OP": "+"`) that match the regex:

- `^` - start of the token
- `(?i:` - start of a case insensitive modifier group:

  - `sq(?:uare)?` - `sq` or `square`
  - `|` - or
  - `m(?:et(?:er|re)s?)?` - `m`, `meter`/`metre` or `meters`/`metres`
- `)` - end of the group
- `$` - end of the string (token here).

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this. I accepted the answer, it works, but there is still something unclear. When trying your example case 4 and 5 do not show the full `square meters` string, but just `square`. Therefore, I tried to remove `meters` from the input string and as expected it still match, is there a way to force matching on the full `square meters` string?

Comment: @DarioB Add  `, "OP": "+"` to `pattern2` regex token, same as in `pattern1`.

Comment: I see, yeah, it works, is there a way to remove the duplicate matching, or a good way to handle it? my new output is  `4898162435462687487 Surface 0 6 the surface is about 31 square 4898162435462687487 Surface 0 6 the surface is about 31 square meters` thanks

Comment: @DarioB Since you have the same starting index I think [this solution of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58817432/3832970) will help here, too.

Comment: hey, I am struggling with spacy regex, it doesn't look the same than traditional regex, where can I learn about it? I am trying to match instead of `square meters` the italian translation `metri quadrati` or `mq` or `metri q`. Could you please help?

Comment: @DarioB It is exactly the traditional Python `re` regex. Just it matches the token text, not the document or sentence. Use `^(?:metri|quadrati|m?q)$`. The point is that you cannot match several tokens with this regex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! if interested I have another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070106/spacy-rule-matcher-extract-value-from-matched-sentence :)